# XWPFDocument replace paragraphe in a loop

Tags: java, javafx, apache-poi, docx

I have a table that contains items. I want to set the names of items in the word document but each one in a new line.

So I created the void below:

When my text contain "P01" I replace the text by the name, add a new line and set another text "P01".

```
public void findAndRemplaceString(XWPFDocument doc, String champs) throws IOException {
    for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
        java.util.List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
        if (runs != null) {
            for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                String text = r.getText(0);
                if (text != null && text.contains("P01")) {
                    text = text.replace("P01", champs);
                    System.out.println("text replaced");
                    r.setText(text, 0);
                    //add new line
                    r.addBreak();
                    //new "P01" added
                    r.setText("P01");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So that the next name of item will be replaced in the paragraph below.

```
@FXML
void endButton(ActionEvent event) {
    String file = "model";
    for (Person item : table.getItems()) {
        //get the name of item
        String a = item.getName();
        // get the index of item
        int ind0 = table.getItems().indexOf(item);
        int ind1 = table.getItems().indexOf(item) + 1;
        try {
            XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File(file + ind0 + ".docx")));
            findAndRemplaceString(doc, a);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(file + ind1 + ".docx"));
            doc.write(fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.close();
            doc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("erreur  " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem is:**

It replace only the first name of item and not the others. It doesn't read the new "P01" that I set.

Comment: The `String text = r.getText(0);` explicitly gets only the first text part from the run but after `r.setText(text,0); r.addBreak(); r.setText("P01");` there are two text parts. A really good answer is not possible because you are not providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but you could try `String text = r.text();` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, it's not the best but it works.

I changed the type of String[] instead of String, so that i can do it this way :

```
public void findAndRemplaceString(XWPFDocument doc,String champs[]){       
    for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {       
        java.util.List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
        if (runs != null) {            
            for (XWPFRun r : runs) {            
                String text = r.getText(0);            
                if (text != null && text.contains("P01") ) {
                    for (int i=0;i<champs.length;i++){
                        text = text.replace("P01","");
                        r.setText(text,0);   //Replace the old text 
                        r.setText(champs[i]);//add the new text
                        r.addBreak();        //new line
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I click the button, the void findAndReplaceString is called only once instead of looping, so I put all the item names in a list like that:

```
@FXML void endButton(ActionEvent event) {
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();        
for (Person item : table.getItems()) {       
    String a = item.getName();
    list.add(a);
}     
String[] simpleArray = new String[list.size()];
list.toArray(simpleArray);
try{   
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File("input.docx")));               
    findAndRemplaceString(doc,simpleArray);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.docx")); 
    doc.write(fileOutputStream);
    fileOutputStream.close();
    doc.close();                    
}catch (Exception e) { 
    System.out.println("erreur  " + e);
    }
}
```